# Is it possible to implement a custom behavior for 3D Touch on links with WKWebView?

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview, 3dtouch, peek-pop

I'm trying to add my own implementation of 3D touch on links with `WKWebView` so I set the `allowsLinkPreview` property of my `WKWebView` to `false`.

But then, impossible to check whether the 3D touch was on a link and impossible to know what link neither.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to set the `allowsLinkPreview` property to `true` and then to catch the peek event that's triggered when 3D Touching a link?

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this?

Comment: Nope sorry, couldn't figure this out

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You should set the `allowsLinkPreview` value to `true` and then implement the following methods. Both methods need implemented or else it won't work.

```
optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,  previewingViewControllerForElement elementInfo: WKPreviewElementInfo,  defaultActions previewActions: [WKPreviewActionItem]) -> UIViewController?
optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,  commitPreviewingViewController previewingViewController: UIViewController)
```

In my case, I didn't want to create a previewViewController so I just returned an `SFSafariViewController` and passed in my url. That seemed to work perfectly. As for the `commitPreviewingViewController` method, that is where I put my code to open up a new tab in my browser.

Source: [iOS 10 Link Preview API in WKWebView](https://webkit.org/blog/7016/ios-10-link-preview-api-in-wkwebview/)